# Convert FILE_URI to NATIVE_URI or vice versa in ionic 3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova Camera plugin to get image from gallery, in IOS when I use FILE_URI to upload image to server all the meta-data attached to the image is stripped out.

However, when I use the NATIVE_URI I get all the meta-data on the server. But, I am not able to show the selected image to the user.

FILE_URI works perfectly in android.

The only solution I can think of is to use FILE_URI for showing image to user and use NATIVE_URI for the server. But I can't seem to find a way to convert it.
Is there any better solution to this problem?

Comment: Using 'File' plugin.